# Creating RSACryptoServiceProvider using own values

Tags: parameters, key, customization, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I need to create a RSACryptoServiceProvider and its parameters to en-/decrypt data.

But I need to en-/decrypt the data again tomorrow using the same keys.
Exporting and storing them in files would be just great but... there's no chance to write files (they don't want me to). So I thought I'd create my own RSACryptoServiceProvider by my own keys and parameters I retrieve from the system. I've got data like processorID, Mac and stuff.

So there's my question.

Can I use some custom strings to create a RSACryptoServiceProvider and repeat that tomorrow getting the same key ?

AFAIK, the RSACryptoServiceProvider parameters have values like p, d, n and stuff. But I also heard that they need to be specific prime numbers.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are doing this in c#, but you can do this if you have a pfx file:

```
 var certBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"path\to\certificate.pfx");
 var privateAndPublicKeyCert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certBytes, "password");
 // pfx files that have a private key should be protected by a password
 var privateKeyCSP = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateAndPublicKeyCert.PrivateKey;
```

Obviusly you have to take care of the security aspects. like **do not hardcode the password** like that.

You will have two ChryptoServiceProvider initialized with values stored in the file...